# Is it possible to highlight a text in Bold or colour using log4j or logback

Tags: log4j, log4j2, logback

I wanted to highlight a particular longline something like

log.info("Framework expects static IP);

Answer (score 0):

you can use color convert in patter.logback support some color convert .
ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.color.ForegroundCompositeConverterBase class child

```
        <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <encoder>
                <pattern>%red(%msg) %n</pattern>
                <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
```